# Haskell, passing a function to filter in one line?

Tags: haskell

I want to filter everything that is not divisible by 3 from a list in Haskell, this is technically what I want to do

```
filter (`mod` 3) [1..100]
```

The problem is, mod x 3 won't return a boolean value.  Is there a way to do this in one line? or am I forced to write another function which returns a boolean value?  I've read about curried functions, but I'm not sure if its possible to do this because if I used (==) a b and a is a function, it just wouldn't work out.

Comment: The list might be an arbitrary one though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use dot notation

```
filter ((== 0) . (`mod` 3)) [1..100]
```

this generates

```
[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99]
```

The type signature of dot is as follows:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Comment: Every Haskell implementation has to provide the `(.)` operator from the automatically imported `Prelude` module (see [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010), [Chapter 9](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#verbatim-196)). GHC might define `(.)` in `GHC.Base` and reexport it from `Prelude`, but for a Haskell programmer, that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes that's right. I would delete it from the answer.

Answer (score 9):

That is what function composition is for:

```
filter ((== 0) . (`mod` 3)) [1..100]
```

As ever, contemplate the types of the involved functions until everything feels natural.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to define it in one line and don't want to write another function (which is going to be used in just one place anyway), the easiest way is to define [lambda function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function):

```
filter (\x -> x `mod` 3 == 0) [1..100]
```

[Point-free](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style suggested in other answers can sometimes lead to "hard to read" expressions when the auxiliary function is more complex then this. Especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
[x | x <- [1..100], (x `mod` 3) == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative version, using streams:

```
takeWhile (<=100) $ map (*3) [1..]
```